# Find the file which does not contain that Word in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I want to find out those files whose does not contain Ctr+F word in folders.

Like If I search "word" in Notepad++, it will show me the files that have this word. But I want to find or see the files those does not contain a "word" search. So I can update that files only.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this from the command prompt. From the Start menu, open up a command prompt, then use `cd` to change to the directory you want to search in. The `help find` command will give you an overview, but in brief this command will print how many times a string is found in each file:

```
find /c "find me" *
```

Any file with a count of 0 will not have the string you're looking for.

Comment: That's not working for me.

Comment: Are the files in subdirectories? The `find` command doesn't search subdirectories. There is a command `findstr /l /s /m "find me" *` which will look in subdirectories, but can't be made to show files without the string, this example will print all files that have the string. You would have to compare the listed files to see what's missing, those are the ones without a match.